# Initialize and use Firestore in both native iOS and Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Our app was developed for iOS and Android with separate code bases and we want to start using Flutter for more rapid development. We already use Firebase SDKs in native code for a variety of services, such as Authentication, FCM and Firestore. We developed a Flutter module that basically uses the same Firebase functionality, utilizing the Firebase Plugin for Flutter. This all works fine for Android, but iOS is a whole different story.

When I open the app and navigate to a Flutter screen, the app crashes with the following exception:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FIRIllegalStateException', reason: 'Firestore instance has already been started and its settings can no longer be changed. You can only set settings before calling any other methods on a Firestore instance.'

In fact, [this closed issue on GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9582) describes the exact same problem. A maintainer suggests to perform all Firestore operations in Flutter only. This poses a problem for us as we already have so much functionality in native code and it would probably require a huge refactor before we can start integrating our first Flutter screens.

So, I think my question consists of two parts:

1. Is it possible to initialize and use Firestore (and other Firebase functionality) in both native iOS (Swift UI) and Flutter?
2. If not, is there a low-cost solution to create an adapter from native to Flutter code for executing Firestore operations?

Comment: No new insights, but reading the github issue response from them cracks me up XD. Basically just said: "Go rewrite your entire app to handle the data within Flutter"

Comment: I know, right? In the meantime we’re experimenting with Firebase initialization in Flutter and then messaging the native code when it successfully fetches any document from Firestore. It feels a bit awkward, but it seems to work for now. I’ll post an update when we have more reliable results.

Comment: Did you all run into issues converting android over for Firebase? I've got a bug currently where it's upset about me declaring dependencies within my build.gradle and also using firebase higher up in my parent flutter application. Thoughts on where I can identify which android firebase package versions I should use that are compatible with the flutter firebase packages?

Comment: The question will likely be closed because it asks for recommendations/opinions, which is off-topic for SO. To answer the question, yes, you can use Firestore from Swift and Flutter. But, Flutter is cross-platform; so would would need to re-write code to flutter-ize it. The question states you already have native code on two platforms, so you're already supporting those and adding flutter would be a third, right? If the goal is to support *one code base*, then re-writing that code in Flutter and eliminating the existing code would do that. Otherwise you're supporting *three* code bases.

Comment: @Jay I disagree. Flutter's Firebase plugin uses the Swift's native Firebase libraries under the hood and that causes initialization problems. It seems that both Swift's library and Flutter's plugin want to configure Firebase, but you can only do this once. I'm not asking for the best or prettiest way to do this. I'm asking for any setup that allows us to use Firestore in both Swift and Flutter, without rewriting our entire code base at once. We want to develop new features using Flutter first and, in time, we will rewrite the native code features to Flutter as well.

Comment: Flutter can be added to an existing project and not interfere with your existing code. My guess is either it's not being initialized correctly, or the modules were not added - however, since we don't know what your code looks like, that's just a guess. We used CocoaPods to add the dependency to our existing macOS app and it was pretty seamless. There's an entire section on the Flutter website dedicated to what you're doing; adding Flutter screens to an existing pp. See it here [Add flutter to an existing app](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/add-to-app). Is that not a solution?

Comment: We are currently running into the same issue: 2 native apps (iOS and Android), in which we have added a Flutter module. Using other Firebase services works as expected, but not Firestore on iOS, due to the error mentioned in the initial post. I was wondering if anybody found a solution in the last year, since this post was created?

Comment: We've found a workaround that defines different projects for native and flutter. This worked, but it has its own problems. Even though they're using the same Firebase project – they simply have different names in the config – you'd have to share the auth state in an awkward way. We did that using Firebase custom tokens. I wouldn't say it's stable as there are some other services that don't work as expected and the team decided to move away from Flutter as a complete rewrite is not an option. Perhaps there's something we did wrong, but we couldn't find a solution to the problem.